# How to return HTTP Get request response from models class in Django project

Tags: python, django, openai-api, openai-assistants-api

I am trying to Get a response from the OpenAi assistants API using a Django project.

I implement a model class inside models.py as such:

```
from django.db import models
from typing_extensions import override
from openai import AssistantEventHandler
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your models here.

class Eventhandler(models.Model,AssistantEventHandler):
class meta:
 managed = False

 @override
 def on_text_created(self, text) -> None:
  print(f"\nassistant > ", end="", flush=True)
  
 @override
 def on_text_delta(self, delta, snapshot):
  print(delta.value, end="", flush=True)
  
def on_tool_call_created(self, tool_call):
 print(f"\nassistant > {tool_call.type}\n", flush=True)

def on_tool_call_delta(self, delta, snapshot):
 if delta.type == 'code_interpreter':
  if delta.code_interpreter.input:
    print(delta.code_interpreter.input, end="", flush=True)
  if delta.code_interpreter.outputs:
    print(f"\n\noutput >", flush=True)
    for output in delta.code_interpreter.outputs:
      if output.type == "logs":
        print(f"\n{output.logs}", flush=True)
```

Now, **what is important** is that the Eventhandler class sends the response back to the client!
I am a getting an exception of type: ValueError:
*The view theassistantcallerapp.views.callerview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.*  Now, **callerview is the view inside views.py**. It maps to the URL that will start the GET request to the OpenAi Assistants API.

This implementation I am using is for streaming responses. Now, here is the view insides views.py and **NOTICE HOW THE EVENTHANDLER CLASS IS USED**

```
#inside views.py
# this is  callerview(request, paramm):

thread = client.beta.threads.create()

message = client.beta.threads.messages.create( thread_id=thread.id,role="user",
        content=otro)   

myeventhandler = Eventhandler() <-----------NOTICE HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!

with client.beta.threads.runs.create_and_stream(
thread_id=thread.id,
assistant_id="asst_dddfffggg",
instructions="Please address the user as Donkey Kong. The user has a premium account.",
event_handler=myeventhandler,  <-----------NOTICE HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   ) as stream:
  stream.until_done()
```

How can I make the class Eventhandler inside models.py return the response from the OpenAi Assistants API ?